# R warning - longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to perform clustering on spatial data based on distance but constrain the cluster size. I found this article online, ([Spatial Clustering With Equal Sizes](http://statistical-research.com/spatial-clustering-with-equal-sizes/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=spatial-clustering-with-equal-sizes)), and it works with a small list of date into 3 clusters.

However, when I tried to run a larger list and cluster them into 30 clusters, it doesn't work as expected. The clusters it returns are uneven again, like below.

I tried the smaller data with 30 cluster and also the example dataset, they both worked out evenly. So I guess it's something wrong with my data. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

> table( cl_constrain$cluster )
>
> Cluster  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
>   Size 151  63  67  88  65  89  92  82  72  84
>
> Cluster 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
>   Size 60  61  44  46  60  51  65 216  56 188
>
> Cluster 20  21  22  23  24  25 26  27  28  29  30
>   Size 229  78 101  75 196 70 222  62 102 271

My data set looks as this

[image]

I'm new to R, and not sure what's going wrong with it, could anyone help me out please? Thanks a lot!

Here's the source code from the article.

```
# Convert to radian
as_radians = function(theta=0){
return(theta * pi / 180)
}

calc_dist = function(fr, to) {
lat1 = as_radians(fr$lat)
lon1 = as_radians(fr$lon)
lat2 = as_radians(to$lat)
lon2 = as_radians(to$lon)
a = 3963.191;
b = 3949.903;
numerator = ( a^2 * cos(lat2) )^2 + ( b^2 * sin(lat2) ) ^2
denominator = ( a * cos(lat2) )^2 + ( b * sin(lat2) )^2
radiusofearth = sqrt(numerator/denominator) #Accounts for the ellipticity of the earth.
d = radiusofearth * acos( sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2 - lon1) )
d.return = list(distance_miles=d)
return(d.return)
}

raw.og = read.csv("http://statistical-research.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/sample_geo.txt", header=T, sep="\t")

orig.data = raw.og[,1:3]

dirichletClusters_constrained = function(orig.data, k=5, max.iter =50, tolerance = 1, plot.iter=TRUE) {
fr = to = NULL

r.k.start = sample(seq(1:k))
n = nrow( orig.data )
k.size = ceiling(n/k)
initial.clusters = rep(r.k.start, k.size)

if(n%%length(initial.clusters)!=0){
exclude.k = length(initial.clusters) - n%%length(initial.clusters)
} else {
exclude.k = 0
}
orig.data$cluster = initial.clusters[1:(length(initial.clusters)-exclude.k)]
orig.data$cluster_original = orig.data$cluster

## Calc centers and merge
mu = cbind( by(orig.data$Latitude, orig.data$cluster, mean), by(orig.data$Longitude, orig.data$cluster, mean), seq(1:k) )
tmp1 = matrix( match(orig.data$cluster, mu[,3]) )
orig.data.centers = cbind(as.matrix(orig.data), mu[tmp1,])[,c(1:2,4:6)]

## Calc initial distance from centers
fr$lat = orig.data.centers[,3]; fr$lon = orig.data.centers[,4]
to$lat = orig.data.centers[,1]; to$lon = orig.data.centers[,2]
orig.data$distance.from.center = calc_dist(fr, to)$distance_miles
orig.data$distance.from.center_original = orig.data$distance.from.center

## Set some initial configuration values
is.converged = FALSE
iteration = 0
error.old = Inf
error.curr = Inf

while ( !is.converged && iteration < max.iter ) { # Iterate until threshold or maximum iterations

if(plot.iter==TRUE){
plot(orig.data$Longitude, orig.data$Latitude, col=orig.data$cluster, pch=16, cex=.6,
xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude")
}
iteration = iteration + 1
start.time = as.numeric(Sys.time())
cat("Iteration ", iteration,sep="")
for( i in 1:n ) {
# Iterate over each observation and measure the distance each observation' from its mean center
# Produces an exchange. It takes the observation closest to it's mean and in return it gives the observation
# closest to the giver, k, mean
fr = to = distances = NULL
for( j in 1:k ){
# Determine the distance from each k group
fr$lat = orig.data$Latitude[i]; fr$lon = orig.data$Longitude[i]
to$lat = mu[j,1]; to$lon = mu[j,2]
distances[j] = as.numeric( calc_dist(fr, to) )
}

# Which k cluster is the observation closest.
which.min.distance = which(distances==min(distances), arr.ind=TRUE)
previous.cluster = orig.data$cluster[i]
orig.data$cluster[i] = which.min.distance # Replace cluster with closest cluster

# Trade an observation that is closest to the giving cluster
if(previous.cluster != which.min.distance){
new.cluster.group = orig.data[orig.data$cluster==which.min.distance,]

fr$lat = mu[previous.cluster,1]; fr$lon = mu[previous.cluster,2]
to$lat = new.cluster.group$Latitude; to$lon = new.cluster.group$Longitude
new.cluster.group$tmp.dist = calc_dist(fr, to)$distance_miles

take.out.new.cluster.group = which(new.cluster.group$tmp.dist==min(new.cluster.group$tmp.dist), arr.ind=TRUE)
LocationID = new.cluster.group$LocationID[take.out.new.cluster.group]
orig.data$cluster[orig.data$LocationID == LocationID] = previous.cluster
}

}

# Calculate new cluster means
mu = cbind( by(orig.data$Latitude, orig.data$cluster, mean), by(orig.data$Longitude, orig.data$cluster, mean), seq(1:k) )
tmp1 = matrix( match(orig.data$cluster, mu[,3]) )
orig.data.centers = cbind(as.matrix(orig.data), mu[tmp1,])[,c(1:2,4:6)]
mu = cbind( by(orig.data$Latitude, orig.data$cluster, mean), by(orig.data$Longitude, orig.data$cluster, mean), seq(1:k) )

## Calc initial distance from centers
fr$lat = orig.data.centers[,3]; fr$lon = orig.data.centers[,4]
to$lat = orig.data.centers[,1]; to$lon = orig.data.centers[,2]
orig.data$distance.from.center = calc_dist(fr, to)$distance_miles

# Test for convergence. Is the previous distance within the threshold of the current total distance from center
error.curr = sum(orig.data$distance.from.center)

error.diff = abs( error.old - error.curr )
error.old = error.curr
if( !is.nan( error.diff ) && error.diff < tolerance ) {
is.converged = TRUE
}

# Set a time to see how long the process will take is going through all iterations
stop.time = as.numeric(Sys.time())
hour.diff = (((stop.time - start.time) * (max.iter - iteration))/60)/60
cat("\n Error ",error.diff," Hours remain from iterations ",hour.diff,"\n")

# Write out iterations. Can later be used as a starting point if iterations need to pause
write.table(orig.data, paste("C:\\optimize_iteration_",iteration,"_instore_data.csv", sep=""), sep=",", row.names=F)
}

centers = data.frame(mu)
ret.val = list("centers" = centers, "cluster" = factor(orig.data$cluster), "LocationID" = orig.data$LocationID,
"Latitude" = orig.data$Latitude, "Longitude" = orig.data$Longitude,
"k" = k, "iterations" = iteration, "error.diff" = error.diff)

return(ret.val)
}

# Constrained clustering
cl_constrain = dirichletClusters_constrained(orig.data, k=4, max.iter=5, tolerance=.0001, plot.iter=TRUE)
table( cl_constrain$cluster )
plot(cl_constrain$Longitude, cl_constrain$Latitude, col=cl_constrain$cluster, pch=16, cex=.6,
xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude")

library(maps)
map("state", add=T)
points(cl_constrain$centers[,c(2,1)], pch=4, cex=2, col='orange', lwd=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an same-size cluster k-means variation in ELKI.

It is explained in detail in [this tutorial](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/SameSizeKMeans).

I have seen a lot of people ask for such a clustering algorithm, but I do not think it is well supported by theory to use an algorithm like this.

For your use case, you also have the problem of geographic coordinates: k-means uses the mean, but the mean may be inconsistent with your distance function. Consider two points at Longitude -179° and +178°. K-means would use the mean of these two, -0.5° as cluster center. A more sensible choice of cluster center would be at +179.5°, on the very opposite side of the earth.

If your data is constrained to a reasonably small area, it may still work.
To get better quality, you may want to map your data into an appropriate UTM zone. Within one UTM zone, Euclidean distance is a reasonable approximation of distance.